# Why should addChangeListener be in componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I saw this line as an answer to another question on here:

"componentWillMount should be componentDidMount, or else you'll leak event emitters in node."

and I don't really understand it. Can someone explain with more detail?

More info:

Building a react application with flux, as part of the initial render, a child component computes some data. Ideally, after this data is computed, I would like to call an action that updates the store's state with a portion of this new data.

Normally, updating the store's state emits a change event that causes a re-render. However, because the change listener isn't being added until componentDidMount (rather than in componentWillMount), my top level component isn't able to listen for the change that occurs during the initial render and initiate a re-render.

If I move the addChangeListener to componentWillMount that would seem to fix this issue, but the above quote suggests that this is a bad idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is hard to understand what that quote means without more context. What I can tell you is that there are huge differences between the two of those methods.

On one hand, `componentWillMount` is called before the component is actually added to the DOM. This is the last chance you have to update component's state and get it rendered before the component is rendered by the browser.

On the other hand, `componentDidMount` is called once the component has been attached to the DOM (the real one).

What you need really depends on your use case. In general, `componentDidMount` is used to integrate with other libraries (like jQuery), it provides a way to modify the HTML rendered by the component.

I suggest you to read these links:

- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentwillmount
- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount
- https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/use-react-with-other-libraries.html

Comment: The problemi is that if I modify the DOM in `componentDidMount`, when he notices that the DOM diverge from it Virtual one, it gives me errors!

Comment: There's usually a work around for such things. I for one use React with Ace rich text editor, jQuery Resizable, jQuery sortable and many other things that work "outside React's world" and had no problems whatsoever. You have to take care of not changing what React rendered, but you can add new elements in most of the cases. Is hard to help without more information about your task.

Answer (score 4):

I think the prevailing wisdom that listeners should be set in `componentDidMount` because it prevents problems in isomorphic applications is a mistake.  I think in 98% of cases for non-isomorphic applications setting listeners in either `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount` will work the same way, but it is conceptually wrong and in the 2% of cases (such as the example given in the original question) it will do the wrong thing.

There are git issue discussions and comments in the React source code suggesting that it would be preferred that `componentWillMount` wasn't called on the server at all, but if it isn't then problems are created in the checksum test comparing the server prerender to the client initial render.  Having `componentWillMount` on the server means that it isn't executed as part of the component lifecycle in this case, but this is being used as an excuse to not count it as part of the lifecycle in any case.

In fact, `componentWillMount` is exactly the right place to register listeners if you are not creating an isomorphic application.  If you are creating an isomorphic application then you have to make some compromises due to the checksum/lifecycle issue not being ideal in this case (maybe just testing for the server environment and then not registering listeners?).

In non-isomorphic applications adding listeners in `componentWillMount` can save unnecessary re-renders in some cases and will register them in document order.  The advantage of document order is that if you have a way to flush pending events as components are re-rendered (for example, `takeRecords` on a `MutationObserver`) then you can ensure the document is re-rendered top down instead of bottom up, converting the rendering complexity to linear from polynomial.

Additionally, there is no danger period between the initial render and when the listener is registered where the Store can change without triggering a render, causing the view to be out of sync with the Store (the example problem given in the original question).  If the listener is registered in `componentDidMount` you either need to make sure the Store isn't changed in `componentDidMount` calls in children, or else force a re-render/re-sync after registering the listener, which if done in `componentDidMount` is done in reverse document order which may be polynomial complexity (depending on how/if the React `setStates` are aggregated).

Comment: Can you update this answer now that `componentWillMount` is deprecated? I'd love to know where to register listeners and where to deregister them with this change

Comment: @xaphod I haven't worked with this in a while, but here is the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html) on dealing with this issue regarding the deprecation changes.  I haven't reviewed this in detail but the data update race still exists as a problem because they recommend explicitly updating the state after subscribing in `componentDidMount`.  I don't know what is a safe alternative with the new async behaviour.