# How to use jQuery plugin that modify the DOM with Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a question following this post:

[issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4227)

How should I use a jQuery plugin that modify the DOM with react. Like `jimfb` kindly answered to me on GH, React shoud return a pre-rendered component. So my question is, how exaclty call a function like `remodal()` in my example, during the lifecycle of a component?

Comment: From the discussion on GH I understand that you should put the dialog on the render function and show or display it manually, so create your own dialog implementation or put dialog outside the react application. I like the first option more, but it is just a tastes thing

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read my answer here:
[Why should addChangeListener be in componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898571/why-should-addchangelistener-be-in-componentdidmount-instead-of-componentwillmou/30903538#30903538)

But basically, when you need to integrate some existing plugin or code with React, the painless way is to generally call that code on the `componentDidMount` method and do the event listening the old way. If you are with jQuery, that means you should use something like

`$(this.getDOMNode()).find('.some-child').on('click', this.onChildClick)`

By doing it this way, you will miss some of the most important features regarding event delegation in React (see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation) but that should not be a problem unless you wanted to create hundreds of event listeners.